# Java stored procedure UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, oracle, procedure

**Dear Experts**

I am trying to execute oracle procedure mapped to a Java stored procedure but I am receiving the following error:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
System error : java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError
```

I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit

I compiled the source using the Java latest version "Java SE 7u15" and I understand that Oracle 11g R2 is using java 5.0 or 1.5, and since the program is executed from Oracle PLSQL. do I need to downgrade the compile version to 1.5 will that help in solving this issue

*Any suggestions will be appreciated*

Comment: Which Java version are you using, 32/64bit?

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown in the cases when the JVM attempts to read a class file and finds that the major and minor version numbers in the particular class file are not supported.

This happens in the cases when a higher version of Java Compiler is used to generate the class file than the JVM version which is used to execute that class file.

Here are few steps to fix your problem:

1. Find out due to which jar or class file this UnSupportedClassVersionError is coming?
2. Try to compile source code of that jar with the JDK version you are using to run your program, if source is available.
3. If you don't have source try to find the compatible version of that library.
4. Increase the JRE version you are using to run your program.

Check the following links for further information:

http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/01/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html

Comment: I compiled the source using the Java latest version "Java SE 7u15" and I understand that Oracle 11g R2 is using the 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you're using [lower version of Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html), than the driver was compiled to, or 32bit/64bit java vs. oracle mismatch.